# Argparse returns expected data but also ValueError

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm using `argparse` to take input and pass it to a function that takes as arguments two variables and `**kwargs`.

Here's my function:

```
def location_by_coordinate(LAT, LNG, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs:
        coordinate_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=%s&lng=%s&access_token=%s" % (LAT, LNG, current_token)
        r = requests.get(coordinate_url).text
    else:
        coordinate_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=%s&lng=%s&access_token=%s" % (LAT, LNG, current_token)
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            if 'DISTANCE' in kwargs:
                distance = kwargs.get('DISTANCE')
                if distance > 5000:
                    print distance
                    print "max distance is 5000m, value is reassigned to default of 1000m"
                    distance = 1000
                    coordinate_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=%s&lng=%s&access_token=%s" % (LAT, LNG, current_token)
                    r = requests.get(coordinate_url).text
                else:
                    pass
                    coordinate_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=%s&lng=%s&access_token=%s" % (LAT, LNG, current_token)
                    r = requests.get(coordinate_url).text
            if 'FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID' in kwargs:
                fb_places_id = kwargs.get('FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID')
                payload = {'FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID': '%s' % (fb_places_id), 'DISTANCE': '%s' % (DISTANCE)}
                r = requests.get(coordinate_url, params=payload).text
            if 'FOURSQUARE_ID' in kwargs:
                foursquare_id = kwargs.get('FOURSQUARE_ID')
                payload = {'FOURSQUARE_ID': '%s' % (foursquare_id), 'DISTANCE': '%s' % (DISTANCE)}
                r = requests.get(coordinate_url, params=payload).text
            if 'FOURSQUARE_V2_ID' in kwargs:
                foursquare_v2_id = kwargs.get('FOURSQUARE_V2_ID')
                payload = {'FOURSQUARE_V2_ID': '%s' % (foursquare_v2_id), 'DISTANCE': '%s' % (DISTANCE)}
                r = requests.get(coordinate_url, params=payload).text
    #print r
    return r
```

Here's how I'm building the command line parser:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="API Endpoints tester")
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", help="Available commands")

    location_by_parser = subparsers.add_parser("location_by_coordinate", help="location function")
    location_by_parser.add_argument("LAT", help="latitude")
    location_by_parser.add_argument("LNG", help="longitude")
    arguments = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    arguments = vars(arguments)
    command = arguments.pop("command")
    if command == "location_by_coordinate":
        LAT, LNG = location_by_coordinate(**arguments)
    else:
        print "No command provided..."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I try the following:

```
$ python argstest.py location_by_coordinate 40.5949799 -73.9495148
```

I get a correct response from the GET call I make to API endpoint with the function, with all sorts of data, that looks like this:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"latitude":40.595094814,"id":"40169670","longitude":-73.94971014,"name":"2203 Avenue X"},{"latitude":40.595371721,"id":"540102881","longitude":-73.949681161,"name":"America's Keswick"},{"latitude":40.5951,"id":"853669456","longitude":-73.94877,"name":"Little Neck, Long Island"},{"latitude":40.594903,"id":"122281671","longitude":-73.950292,"name":"L A Liquor"},{"latitude":40.594988731,"id":"1015076504","longitude":-73.950396851,"name":"Ballys Gym"},.........
{"latitude":40.594335241,"id":"570423173","longitude":-73.950273475,"name":"Art House Restaurant"}]}
```

However, at the very end, after the data, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "argstest.py", line 117, in <module>
    main()
  File "argstest.py", line 108, in main
    LAT, LNG = location_by_coordinate(**arguments)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What's going on here? Did I not correctly setup my subparsers? What should I do differently?

Comment: 1. Your code works for me just fine (but raises a different error: `NameError: global name 'current_token' is not defined`). 2. Why are you using a subparser and then subparser of a subparser ? all you're handling is 3 arguments...

Comment: Uncomment `#print r` just before the `return` in `location_by_coordinate`  to see if the result is really a tuple with two elements.

Comment: @MikeMüller I think I just made a dumb mistake in the conditional command check at the end with the tuple assignment - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Loks like all options return `url...().text`.  I assume that's a string, possibly a JSON string that you have to convert of a dictionary to get values like latitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that your parser is fine (you can just print the arguments), but your function location_by_coordinate does not return tuple, that why you get this error.
You can always split the line `LAT, LNG = location_by_coordinate(**arguments)` into (for debugging):

```
print(arguments)
res =  location_by_coordinate(**arguments) 
print(res)
LAT, LNG = res
```

to find out what happening

Comment: Thanks, dumb mistake on my part